# How to avoid ID collision when using NHibernate but the database table is updated externally as well?

Tags: .net, oracle, nhibernate, sequence

I am using NHibernate, using XML mapping. The database is ORACLE. A customer entity has something like this

```
<class name="CustomerEntity" table="CUSTOMER">
    <id name="Id" column="ID" type="int">
      <generator class="sequence">
        <param name="sequence">CUSTOMER_ID</param>
      </generator>
    </id>
    ... (something)
 </class>
```

And other objects ID are similarly mapped. However, sometimes users also update the database, like inserting new customers and I am afraid that the ID that they add can collide with the numbers generated by the sequence, which results in an exception and the new customer cannot be added.

Currently I am cheating it by making the sequence starts at a very high value (like 10,000) so that it is not likely that the numbers generated by the sequence is the same as ones entered by users (naturally they will enter stuff like 1, 2, 100, etc.). However this is still risky and not clean.

How to solve this problem? Should I put a try-catch-repeat in all codes? Note that this can still cause problems such as a very long loop if the next many numbers are already used.

Comment: is ID is *manually* entered by 'external' users?

Comment: Interesting question. BTW, it strikes me as *highly* unusual to give users direct write access to a production DB. Could you expand your answer to explain why this is necessary? Consider that in many organizations, directly writing to a production DB is considered a fireable offense, except in dire emergencies.

Comment: @sleske  Yes indeed this is a bit unusual, mainly because the tool to update/add some database values is not ready

Answer (score 5):

If users update the DB directly, they really, *really* should use the sequence as well. That is,

```
INSERT (id, a, b, ...) VALUES (seq.nextval, 'bla', 'blo', ) INTO SOMETABLE
```

If they don't, there is really nothing you can do to avoid collisions.

You *could* check for "occupied" IDs by reading all IDs (`SELECT MAX(ID) FROM SOMETABLE`), then change the sequence to start above that, but of course that only works until some users enters another record.

You could do the "free ID" check before every operation, but that would probably be prohibitively slow.

I can only see two real solutions:

- Make sure all inserts use the sequence to generate IDs. Maybe write a stored procedure for users to use, or some helper program...
- Use a [UUID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UUID) as the ID, instead of an integer. This of course requires a schema change.

And BTW: Why do your users need direct DB access? This strikes me as highly unusual (and dangerous, for many reasons, one of which you describe). Consider somehow controlling / mediating the access, by providing some frontend, or at least some stored procedures. Otherwise user education seems your only option...

Answer (score 2):

You could get triggers to handle Primary key population, then you can forget about populating the primary key.
(similar to an auto-incrementing column)

e.g:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trg_customer_seq
    BEFORE INSERT
    ON customer
    FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
BEGIN
    SELECT seq_customer_id.NEXTVAL
    INTO :NEW.ID
    FROM DUAL;
END;
```

Note: if you are using 11g you now substitute

```
SELECT seq_customer_id.NEXTVAL
INTO :NEW.ID
FROM DUAL;
```

for

```
:MEW.ID := seq_customer_id.NEXTVAL
```